# Bind a ViewBag in an @Html.DropDownList inside of a WebGrid in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, webgrid

I am reading a lot of posts since Last week but there is nothing about my problem.

I have this simple Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AdventureWorks2014Entities db = new AdventureWorks2014Entities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.Products.ToList();
        ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "Name");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And this simple View :

```
@model IEnumerable<ADWork.Client.Models.Product>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ProductID"),
        grid.Column("Name", null, format:@<span>@Html.DropDownList("Products", @item.Name, new { style = "color:red;" }) </span>),
            grid.Column("ListPrice", "Price")
    )
)
```

Now the problem is the DropDownList. I can render it very easy like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Products", null , new { style = "color:red;" })
```

But I want to add the @item.Name to show the default String, and THAT is the problem, it is not working the @ (at sign) inside of the @HTML.DropDownList, it isn't yellow, it is like turn off because the @ in the beginning of the line like I posted in the beginning.

Any Idea how to solve this without creating a new SelectList(blah blah), just converting the @item.Name to String?

Comment: You don't need the at, because you're already in a code block.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch , I tried that long ago and it doesn't work: Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
 Like I said, I tried many things but it does not work

Comment: And there you go.  You can't use a dynamic in a helper like that.  Putting an @ in front of it won't change anything.  You need copy the value to a local variable first and then use that local variable in your helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIND THE SOLUTION AFTER 6 days trying and trying!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ProductID"),
        grid.Column("Name", null, format:
            @<span>
               grid.Column("Name", null, format:
@<span>
    @{
            string name = (@item.Name).ToString();
            @Html.DropDownList("Products", null, name , new { style = "color:red;" });
    }
</span>),
           </span>),
            grid.Column("ListPrice", "Price")
    )
)
```

I had to create a new string with the @item.Name and that's all!!! ufff I saw so many post where people where creating a ViewBag, and later creating a new list in the DropDOwnList that it didn't make sense...well here is the answer!!!